# How can I use app.fragment with LiveData and ViewModel

Tags: java, mvvm, kotlin

I want to use `ViewModelProviders.of` (app.fragment) to create a `ViewModel`, but I find that the function `of` is only supported in the v4 package. What should I do?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do not use `android.app.Fragment`, [the entire class is now deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment). The support library version does everything in a much better, safer, more predictable way.

Comment: Thank you，I just want to know if Google recommends we give up the app.fragment and use v4.